# Is there a way in pandas to get the count_value of a column and then divide it by the sum of another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of matches of League of Legends with the champions played and which team won, and I would like to get a champion count of matches played, and divide it by how many they won to get the win ratio. I can get the amount of times the champions was played with value_count(), but I can't figure out how to sum the result columns depending on the champion played column. The dataframe looks like this.
[image]

Comment: Can you post your data in a reproducible format rather than an image, and give the specific of example of what your desired output is? There is a great reference post on [How to make good, reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check with `mean` : will return the total win percentage

```
df.groupby('top')['result'].mean()
```